# How to rspec test validations for polymorphic attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm attempting my first TDD project in Rails and Rspec. I've finally got some simple boiler plate Rspec code going for model validations. My model `Employee` has polymorphic associations in `Email` and `Address`.

How do I write validations for these polymorphic associations? Besides making sure `validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :role`, I also want to make sure there is presence of emails and address.

Here's my models:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :employee_projects
    has_many :projects, through: :employee_projects
    has_many :phones, as: :phonable, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :emails, as: :emailable, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :addresses, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails, allow_destroy: true

    validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :role 

end
```

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```
class Email < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :emailable, polymorphic: true  
end
```

and here is my Rspec test for `Employee`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Employee, type: :model do
  context 'Validation tests' do 
   subject { described_class.new(first_name: 'first_name', last_name: 'last_name', role: 'role') 
  }

    it 'is valid with attributes' do   
      expect(subject).to be_valid 
    end

    it 'is not valid without first_name' do   
      subject.first_name = nil 
      expect(subject).to_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is not valid without last_name' do
      subject.last_name = nil 
      expect(subject).to_not be_valid 
    end

    it 'is not valid without role' do    
      subject.role = nil 
      expect(subject).to_not be_valid 
    end


 end
end
```

Also hope to start using FactoryBot but want to get the basics first.

Comment: Check out [custom validators](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods). They ought to do the trick.

Comment: What's your rails version. As what I know from Rails 5, `belongs_to` is required and your `subject` in rspec should not be valid.